# CMake : External project remote URL not working

Tags: c++, linux, build, cmake

I want to access my source code from another computer with the same network.

For that I have put my source code on remote location `//10.101.2.143/Source/myCode.tar.gz`

Now I want to extract that source code and put into `/usr/local/fuse/compiler/`

For that I have written in CMakeFile.txt:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  compiler
  URL http://10.101.2.143/Source/myCode.tar.gz
  DOWNLOAD_DIR ${COMPILER_DOWNLOAD_DIR}
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compiler
  BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compiler
  DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  PATCH_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compiler/CMakeLists.txt" <SOURCE_DIR>/CMakeLists.txt
)
```

Its unable to get that remote location code.

I have written one separate CMakeList.txt file at `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/compiler` that extract `tar.gz` file

```
add_custom_target(extract_compiler_tar ALL
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar -zxvf "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/myCode.tar.gz"
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
)
```

Is there any other way/solution to access remote location source code ??

I got stuck in this issue.

Manny thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  # ...
  URL http://10.101.2.143/Source/myCode.ta.gz
  # ...
)
```

It must be **myCode.tar.gz** according to your CmakeList.txt